# How to listend to ALL NFT smart contract events?

Tags: events, nft

I would like log all NFT transfers happening on the blockchain. I know that there is a standard event in the ERC721 smart contract. I actually can subscribe to that event if I know the address of the smartcontract but is it possible to subscribe to all these kind of events ?
I would like to avoid reading all the transactions'data of each blocks ...

thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that those events originate from the NFT smart contracts. So you either have to listen to events from certain (contract) addresses or parse data from each block and try to figure out if they have the types of events you need.

Or then you can use an external service, something like https://thegraph.com/ - although unsure what all it provides.

Comment: the "Transfer" event is in the ERC721 standard. I just want to focus on those ones. I want to avoid parsing data from each block because I would need to do a getTransactionReceipt() on every transaction then parse the logs. which is pretty heavy. That's why i am kind of hoping that there is a way to listen to all of those kind of events.  Also The Graph is cool but the creator of the NFT smart contract needs to deploy a subgraph first. so I would need to subscribe to it, so not what i am looking for.